# Lerna - How to manage an external package using internal symbolic links

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, lerna

I'm not expert at all about Lerna, sorry if the question looks stupid.

What I'd like to archive is manage a set of private NPM packages ( with Lerna in a git mono-repo project  ) and some external git projects who depend upon the Lerna mono-repo.

Practical example:

I have an API client that's shared across frontend and backend as NPM private package under Lerna and if I'll change something in this package I'd like to have all the changes in real time across both projects ( frontend and backend ) without publishing the package.

I would like to manage the API client with Lerna and all the Lerna features in terms of commands but I don't care to manage the frontend and the backend with Lerna ( because are not packages, are applications that are not published on NPM )

Lerna is supposed to manage this such of structure or I have to put everything in a mono-repo?

I would avoid storing the entire React frontend project and dozens of Lambda functions in just one repository because of that. If on one hand, it will simplify the dependencies issue, on the other hand, will overcomplicate the projects management flow in terms of versions/features and cross-team tasks.

Could anyone help me with any useful links about how to do that? ( if is it possible :) )

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you make any progress with this challenge?